# Can't run Jupyter Notebook within Python environment on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I've installed both Anaconda and created a virtual Python3 environment called `Python3`. Before I activate the environment, I can run `jupyter notebook` and open Jupyter. But if I activate the environment and then run:

```
$source activate Python3
$jupyter notebook
```

I would get a `No such file or directory` error, which directed me to using `sudo apt install jupyter`. I did that, but now I get:

```
Error executing Jupyter command 'notebook': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Do I have to perform some PATH trick to make this work?

Comment: may be this could help you: https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter_core/issues/84

Comment: Did you install jupyter in your new environment?

Comment: I've never had to do that after creating a new environment

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue. This is what I did to fix the issue (on **Ubuntu**) :

```
sudo apt-get remove ipython
sudo apt-get purge ipython
sudo apt-get autoremove
pip install jupyter
```

**ipython** seemed to be the problem, hence removing it fixed the issue.

Comment: Have you tried running `Jupyter` using `Anaconda` or `miniconda`?